# Can't supply stored procedure parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
OpenSqlConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReturnCharacterInfo", Con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CharacterID", CharacterID);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

When I run code you can see above, it throws exception

> *Procedure or function 'ReturnCharacterInfo' expects parameter '@CharacterID', which was not supplied.*

but as you can see at the code, I'm suppying `@CharacterID` parameter and it's not empty or null.

Stored procedure:

```
    [ReturnCharacterInfo] @CharacterID int 
as
   select 
      CharacterName, characterSurname, CharacterIsMale, CharacterAge, 
      CharacterMood, CharacterHealth, CharacterInCity, CharacterInLocation, 
      Cities.CityName, Locales.LocaleTitle 
   from 
      Characters 
   INNER JOIN 
      Cities on Cities.CityID = Characters.CharacterInCity
   INNER JOIN 
      Locales on Locales.LocaleID = Characters.CharacterInLocation
   Where 
      CharacterID = @CharacterID
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show the stored procedure, show more of your code.

Comment: It's a stored **procedure** - not *stored produce* as you keep typing ... in English, *produce* are fruits and vegetables and such .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to explicitly specifying the type of the parameter - especially important if the value is null:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReturnCharacterInfo", Con);

// added as per CodeNaked's comment - thanks! You've nailed it right on the head!
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@CharacterID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CharacterID;
```

Also: do you have a typo anywhere?? **Triple-check** all occurrences of `CharacterID` - do you happen to have `CharachterID` or something like that somewhere in your code??

Comment: He also needs `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`.

Comment: Looks like i forgot cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; Thank you @CodeNaked

Answer (score 1):

As CodeNaked pointed out, you need to set the command type of the SqlCommand. The SqlCommand object needs to be told it's a stored procedure because of the way that stored procedures are executed.

```
OpenSqlConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ReturnCharacterInfo", Con);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CharacterID", CharacterID);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```